# Heap blocks size is different in !heap commands

Tags: windbg, heap-memory, heap-dump, heap-corruption, heap-size

Why !heap -p -a gives correct size but !heap -i fails. Is the block corrupted.?

Image upload failed from Android app so uploaded it to reddit -
https://www.reddit.com/r/windbg/comments/i9iq7w/why_does_heap_p_a_command_show_the_block_size_but/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: -p is page heap and before using it you are supposed to enable page heaps for the current process using either gflags gui or command line gflags +hpa have you done it ? also heap format has undergone several changes but  the windbg extension hasnt kept pace and may giveout partial info  copy  the info in image as text to your query